# How can I solve "Uncaught ReferenceError: submitForm is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html code like this :

```
<input type="file" id="file" name='file' onChange="return submitForm();">
```

My javascript code like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm() {
        alert('test');
    }
</script>
```

On the console exist error like this :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: submitForm is not defined
>
> at HTMLInputElement.onchange

How can I solve the error?

**UPDATE**

My full code like this : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/v682-pasy

Comment: The code shown works for me. (But if you're using jQuery why are you using an inline HTML attribute event handler?)

Comment: the code shown is working for me too.

Comment: @nnnnnn, See my question. I had update it

Comment: @Samarth, See my question. I had update it

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question. Second, use a service like jsFiddle.net (https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aegt9j32/) for testing JavaScript issues. It appears what you have on phpfiddle doesn't render properly. Inspect the source and you'll see it removed your script.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is inside the `head` tag you must put the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    function submitForm() {
      alert('test');
    }
  });
</script>
```

[read](https://www.sitepoint.com/types-document-ready/)

Comment: This would break it.The `submitForm()` function must be global if it is to be called from an inline HTML event attribute.